# System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: The message length limit was exceeded

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, windows-store-apps, dotnet-httpclient

I'm developing a rest client app for windows store. Everything went smoothly until received responses were smaller than 64K. I have no idea how to proceed. I tried using HttpClient, checked app capabilities, and searched most properties for any solution with no success.

Most people suggest setting HttpWebRequest.DefaultMaximumResponseHeadersLength or HttpWebRequest.MaximumResponseHeadersLength yet in windows store app those properties are not available(?). Maybe I'm missing some references. Anyhow any suggestion would help, as I exhausted every idea I've come up with.

Exception I'm getting:

> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending
>   the request. ---> System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection
>   was closed: The message length limit was exceeded.
>
> at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult)
>  at
>   System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.GetResponseCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
>
> --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)
>  at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)
>  at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult() ...

Comment: completely unrelated problem (see: exception)

Comment: Point accepted and close vote removed.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `HttpClient.GetAsync()` with `HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead`. This way the response won't be cached.

I.e.:

```
private async void Foo()
{
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

    // Do not cache response, use HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead.
    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(
        "http://localhost/?big=2000000000",
        HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead);

    // Consume response as a System.IO.Stream.
    Stream contentStream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();

    int bytesRead;
    do
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1000000];
        bytesRead = contentStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    } while (bytesRead > 0);
}
```

Comment: Same effect, no difference. Problem still not resolved. Exception thrown on GetAsync.

Comment: Are you sure it is the same exception and it is coming from GetAsync? Also, you must consume the response using ReadAsStreamAsync. Fiddler traces may help in this case.

Comment: Yes, I'm sure and I do consume the message. Any other ideas?